# How to Remove Menu bar from Rhosimulator?

Tags: ruby, rhomobile, rhodes

I am trying to remove top menu bar from rhosimulator but I am unable to achieve that.

Can anybody knows how to do that.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you had try?

Comment: Why do you need to do this, since the rhosimulator is only for development?

Comment: I understand Douglas but the simulator shows the actual view of app that how it's going to be appear after deploying it on production.So, if the menu bar will come there it will be a trouble.

Comment: @Michele d'Amico I am running my app on Rhosimulator and I am getting default menu bar on the top of the app. I want to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to uncomment following line in initialize method of app/application.rb file :

```
#To remove default toolbar uncomment next line:
@@toolbar = nil
```